# Finding the value d in RSA encryption

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This might be stupid question, but I can't figure this out, so please bear with me.

I was looking at this RSA exercise, and I know that the correct value of d is 689. However, I have no idea how to get that number.
I read somewhere that d can be calculated using this:

```
d = e^-1 mod (p-1)*(q-1)
```

Here are the values from the exercise:

```
e = 5
```

I found these myself, but i think they're correct:

```
p = 43
q = 83
```

So:

```
d = 5^-1 mod 3444
```

I don't get how that could ever give me 689. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if you solve $5 \times 689 \pmod{3444}$, what do you get? This is the same as writing $d e = 1 \pmod{3444}$. So, it might be helpful to review http://www.math.cornell.edu/~morris/135/mod.pdf

Comment: Note you can write this as, what $b$ solves $5b-1 = 3444k$, so $5b = 3444k + 1$, we can see for $k = 1$, $b = 689$. (See note I linked above).

Comment: That gives me 1. However, I could only solve that because I knew beforehand that d was 689. What if I didn't know? How would i find d ?

Comment: Modular (multiplicative) inverse is computed using the extended euclidean algorithm (EEA, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) which should have been discussed in your lecture. 689 is the correct result (see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5^(-1) mod 3444 )

Comment: I would strongly recommend reviewing the notes I linked!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strictly use the extended euclidean algorithm to solve
$$d \equiv 5^{-1} \text{ mod } 3444$$
the simplified table you'd get would be

[image: eea table]

(First 2 lines are initialization, the rest is described in e.g. http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/number-theory/exteuc/exteuc.html)

And as a result $d \equiv 689 \text{ mod } 3444$

Answer (score 0):

There are general procedures, such as the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, for finding modular inverses.  But for the modular inverse of  a small number like $5$, we can do it more or less by inspection.

We want $5x\equiv 1\pmod{3444}$. If we can find $k$ such that $1+3444k$ is divisible by $5$, we will be finished, for then we can cancel the $5$'s.

Note that $k=1$ works. So we want to solve $5x\equiv 1+3444\pmod{5}$. We get $x=\frac{1+3444}{5}$.